# How to Read Video/MP4 Details with Python?

Tags: python, mp4

I am trying to build a program for sorting and recommending movies from my library of mp4s. I have a collection of movies in mp4 format with genre, director and release year saved in the details. In a Python script, I want to read the title and details for every file in the folder, organize that information into a dataset, and then generate a list of randomly chosen titles based on a set of user provided criteria for director, genre, release year, run time, etc.

I know how to get the list of files in the directory and what to do with the data once it is in Python; however, I cannot figure out how to get the information from the file details. The [Tinytag](https://pypi.org/project/tinytag/) library is really close to what I want; however, that package returns information relevant to music and not movies. Is there another package or function that is able to extract all of the details, not just some? I would prefer if I did not have to save the director names as "Composers" in the details for every movie.

It would be great if there was a way to write to the details as well (save a comment or rating after the movie), but that is not essential.

Answer (score 0):

The MP3 and MP4 file formats are not the same.  Most MP4 files don't have that kind of metadata at all.  If you have a tool that has consistently placed a metadata block in the file, then you may have to use a hex editor to go look for it.

Comment: That's interesting. Tinytag has been able to get release year from the mp4 files, which gave me the impression that the files were storing the data in a similar enough way. I have also seen some mention of FFMPEG, but that seems more focused on command line code. Do you have any recommendations for resources for using hex editors?

Comment: If you're on Linux, you probably have the hexdump command.  `hexdump -C xxx.mp4 | more`.